# Entity Framework Core - No Lazy Loading and when using Include() it goes to deeply

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have entity in my model that has some references through navigation properties to other objects, and even some collection navigation properties.

When I use standard query like this:

```
DatabaseContext.Set<MyEntity>().ToListAsync();
```

Then there are only Foreign Keys returned and all navigation properties are null!

Then I make something like this.

```
 DatabaseContext.Set<MyEntity>()
                .Include(e => e.Child1)
                .Include(e => e.Child2)
                .ToListAsync();
```

(**Child 1** and **Child 2** are principal entities and **Foreign Keys** are in **MyEntity**)

Then query returns list of **MyEntity** entities with loaded reference entities **Child1** and **Child2**. But here is the problem that it also `loads all Child1, Child2 collection navigation properties` like `Child1.List<Child1SubChild>`.

So it makes **multilevel Include()**, but I would like to have only one level of loading of direct childs, without sub-childs, etc.

Comment: Lazy loading is not currently supported in EF Core. See [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3797).

Comment: I know but it means I couldn't get entity + its only direct references entities (without deep hierarchy?)

Comment: Are the collection navigation properties inside Child1 & Child2 of type either of MyEntity/Child1/Child2?